# Spring LdapTemplate - attribute 'gidNumber' not allowed exception

Tags: spring, ldap, jndi, spring-ldap

I'm trying to control OpenLDAP using Spring LDAPTemplate.

In LDAP, I've groups and users organization units. I'm trying to bind new users into LDAP with group association. (*Generic User Account*) So when I try to bind a new user, I also put `gidNumber` attiribute into attributes object. But I'm getting an error like this:

```
[LDAP: error code 65 - attribute 'gidNumber' not allowed]; nested exception is javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - attribute 'gidNumber' not allowed]; remaining name 'ou=staff'
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
DistinguishedName dn = new DistinguishedName();
dn.add("ou", "staff");
Attributes attributes = new BasicAttributes();
attributes.put("objectClass", "inetOrgPerson");
attributes.put("uid", username);
attributes.put("givenName", name);
attributes.put("gidNumber", gidNumber.toString());
attributes.put("sn", surname);
attributes.put("cn", name + " " + surname);
attributes.put("userPassword", password);
ldapTemplate.bind(dn, null, attributes);
```

Here's my schema:

```
+--> dc=ibu,dc=edu,dc=tr (5)
  ---> cn=admin
  +--> ou=group (1)
    | ---> cn=Academic
  ---> ou=guest
  +--> ou=staff (2)
    | ---> cn=John Clark
  ---> ou=student
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another object class called posixAccount. Because the attribute gidNumber belongs to this class. So try adding one more object class as follows:

```
attributes.put("objectClass", "posixAccount");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply; but now I'm getting another exception: `LDAP: error code 65 - no structural object class provided`

Answer (score 0):

An LDAP entry must just have one *and only one* structural object class. Some broken servers do allow multiple structural object classes, though. Add a structural object class (the one to add depends on the purpose for which the entry is used).

Comment: I updated question, added my LDAP schema. Can you explain more briefly how can I add this dependency **using Spring LDAP**? For example if I want to add a user into **Academic** group, how can I express this?